# Average time it takes to get a sample above some threshold level in normal distribution

Tags: time-series, probability, normal-distribution

I am sampling a normally distributed noise signal (digital recording) with some arbitrary mean and standard deviation, where a single sample is received each second (1 sample / 1 sec).

I am interested in:

1.) The average time it takes to get a sample above +6 $\sigma$ ?

2.) The average time between two successive samples above +6 $\sigma$ ?

My attempt

Probability for sample to be above +6 $\sigma$ is $ p = 1-\frac{1}{2} (1+erf(\frac{6}{\sqrt{2}})$, then the average time for sample above +6 $\sigma$ to occur is 1/$p$ * 1 [sec].

Assuming memory-less system I think that 1.) and 2.) should be the same.

I would also like o know if this problem could be solved in the context of failure rates analysis (mean time between failures) where a sample above some threshold level would define system/component failure.

Comment: Yes you are correct. The number of i.i.d. Bernoulli trials until the first success(failure) follows a geometric distribution, and the expectation is what you have put down. I am not sure how your follow-up question different from this.